# Accessing USB stick without drive letter

Tags: powershell, windows-7

I am using powershell 2.0 in windows 7.

I would like to copy a file from my USB stick to a directory on my main hard drive using cmd or powershell. However, I need this to function on any PC without any input of the USB's current drive letter. In case that didn't make sense, let me rephrase it. I need a powershell or cmd command/ batch script to copy a file from my USB stick to my hard drive without any input.

Ideal command would assign the variable mydrive to the drive letter and allow me to run something like this in cmd

```
copy myvar:/path/fileToCopy.txt/ C:/path/of/target/directory/
```

I would really appreciate if I could use just my USB sticks name ('DD') to copy like this:

```
copy DD:/path/fileToCopy.txt/ C:/path/of/target/directory/
```

I've done well over an hours worth of research trying to find a way to pull this off and can't. Any help is greatly appreciated. Especially if it is clear how to use it. I am very new to powershell and cmd commands and don't understand the syntax. So stuff like [put drive name here] to show me how to use it would be amazing and is where a lot of forums are missing out.

Comment: can you just put the script on the USB storage? then run it from there ... no need to know the drive that way.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey I can't actually put the script on the USB storage without the path to the USB storage.

Comment: sorry, i thot you had the device and could simply store the script there. ///// you could keep track of the drives in your system - perhaps put the list in the script - and then simply go for "the new one" that shows up when you connect the device. ///// another is to see if there is an event log entry when a new device connects. you can trigger task scheduler via events ... i don't know how to do that, tho. [*blush*]

Comment: Hmm alright. I might try that. Thanks

Comment: you are welcome! glad to kinda-sorta help ... [*grin*]

Comment: So you don't really care what happens in the background as long as you dont have to give any input, correct? Then you can get the path to the drive like `(get-psdrive | Where-Object {$_.name -eq "DD"}).Root`

Comment: 32 or 64-bit Windows 7?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this like below:

```
$destination = 'C:\path\of\target\directory'
$sourceFile  = 'path\fileToCopy.txt'           # the path to the file without drive letter

# get (an array of) USB disk drives currently connected to the pc
$wmiQuery1 = 'ASSOCIATORS OF {{Win32_DiskDrive.DeviceID="{0}"}} WHERE AssocClass = Win32_DiskDriveToDiskPartition'
$wmiQuery2 = 'ASSOCIATORS OF {{Win32_DiskPartition.DeviceID="{0}"}} WHERE AssocClass = Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition'

$usb = Get-WmiObject Win32_Diskdrive | Where-Object { $_.InterfaceType -eq 'USB' } | 
    ForEach-Object {
        Get-WmiObject -Query ($wmiQuery1 -f $_.DeviceID.Replace('\','\\'))   #'#  double-up the backslash(es)
    } | 
    ForEach-Object {
        Get-WmiObject -Query ($wmiQuery2 -f $_.DeviceID)
    }

# loop through these disk(s) and test if the file to copy is on it
$usb | ForEach-Object {
    # join the DeviceID (like 'H:') with the file path you need to copy
    $file = Join-Path -Path $_.DeviceID -ChildPath $sourceFile
    if (Test-Path -Path $file -PathType Leaf) {
        Copy-Item -Path $file -Destination $destination
        break  # exit the loop because you're done
    }
}
```

Hope that helps

<sup>If you upgrade your version of PowerShell, you can replace the `Get-WmiObject` with `Get-CimInstance` for better performance. See [this](https://blog.ipswitch.com/get-ciminstance-vs-get-wmiobject-whats-the-difference) and [that](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/should-i-use-cim-or-wmi-with-windows-powershell/)</sup>